# When is it best to use JOIN or UNION?

Tags: sql, database, join, union

Suppose I have three tables:

Primaries:

[image: | id | uuid | passportId | name | |:---- |:------:| -----:|-----:| | 1 | uuid-1111 | passportId1 | A Primary | | 2 | uuid-2222 | passportId2 | Another Primary |]

Dependents:

[image]

Transactions:

[image: | id | borrowerUuid (FK: Primaries.uuid & Dependents.uuid) | |:---- |:------:| | 1 | uuid-1111 | | 2 | uuid-3333 | | 3 | uuid-4444 |]

I am just wondering, what is the SQL operation that I have to use in order for me to get the passportId for each borrower? Should I use JOIN or UNION? And what would be the difference for the both of them given my schema above?

Output Expected:

[image: | transactionId | borrowerUuid | name | primaryPassportId | |:---- |:------:| -----:|-----:| | 1 | uuid-1111 | A Primary | passportId1 | | 2 | uuid-3333 | A Dependent | passportId1 | | 3 | uuid-4444 | Another Dependent | passportId2 |]

Comment: UNION is about merging *sets of rows* to create a superset of the rows. All of the rows must have matching columns. JOIN is about *widening* rows, adding more columns. There shouldn't ever be a "do I use UNION or JOIN" since they do *very different* things.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever so basically a UNION is for two tables with identical columns?

Comment: I'd usually phrase it as "result sets" rather than tables, since you may e.g. just select common columns from larger tables, or be working with the results of subqueries, etc, but that's the general gist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `left join`s and `coalesce()`:

```
select t.*, coalesce(p.passportid, dp.passportid) as passportid
from transactions t left join
     primaries p
     on t.borroweruuid = p.uuid left join
     dependents d
     on t.borroweruuid = d.uuid left join
     primaries pd
     on pd.id = d.primaryid;
```

The first `left join` matches directly to the `primaries` table.  The second matches through the `dependents`.

Comment: Man, I'll definitely read your book because of this ;)

Answer (score 1):

UNION is combining 2 tables that have the same columns into one it will add one table under the other (will remove duplicate records) union all will leave the duplication

Join will add columns from 2 different columns tables by a specific logic

in you case you cannot use Union as None of the tables are the same
you need to use Join

```
select t.*, p.passportid, p.passportid , p.name
from transactions t left join
     primaries p
     on t.borroweruuid = p.uuid
```